# React lazy load components after user logs in

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How to lazy load certain components only after the user logs in.

So instead of

```
import { lazy } from 'react';
const MarkdownPreview = lazy(() => import('./MarkdownPreview.js'));
```

that defers loading the component’s code until it’s rendered for the first time, how would I defer the loading until the user is logged in?

Answer (score -1):

You can just use conditional rendering.

```
{userIsLoggedIn && (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          MarkdownPreview />
        </Suspense>
      )
}
```

The goal of lazy import and suspense is to lazy import the component as long it's not rendered. With this we are lazy loading the MarkdownPreview until the user login because we are preventing it to be rendered.

Comment: I think that is incorrect, your MarkdownPreview component is still imported (regardless of being rendered or not), so will probably still end up in the bundle. And that is what I want to achieve, remove it from the bundle, not removing it from the html

Comment: I think you misunderstood the lazy of react. The lazy import of react only imports or bundled the component when it's first render that is the reason you have fallback in suspense. "This will automatically load the bundle containing the component when this component is first rendered." Base on react docs

Comment: You can also check the code splitting technique of react. https://dev.to/franklin030601/code-splitting-in-react-js-4o2g